# R loop for adding dataframes in a dataframe list if each dataframe has more than n rows

Tags: r

I usually code in python and I'm struggling with this problem.

I have a list of dataframe names called dataframe_name and I would like to use this list to call some dataframes objects.
After that I want to use an if loop to pick up the dataframes with number of rows equal to 34 and list them in order to create a list of dataframe objects.

```
dataframe_name<-c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x6","x7")
dataframe_list<-list()

for(i in dataframe_name){
  if(nrow(get(i))==34){
    append(get(i),dataframe_list)
  }
}
```

When I run the script I get this error:

```
Error in if (nrow(get(i)) == 34) { : argument is of length zero
```

What I have understood is that nrow(get(i)) appears to be null but I don't know why.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It looks as if one of your dataframes (`x1` etc) does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have taken the names with  dataframe_name<-names(eapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame)) then I think that all that names have a respective object

Comment: That will include non-dataframes as well.  You need something like `names(sapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame))[sapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame)]` (I'm sure there must be a neater way!

Comment: `names(eapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame))` returns me only the dataframes in my Global Environment. I have controlled

Comment: For me, that includes non-dataframes as well. The `eapply` returns a list of named `TRUE/FALSE` values, and the `names` then just takes the names of these, whether they are true or not.  Try using `dataframe_name <- names(which(sapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame)))`

Comment: I was wrong and you right. Thank you very much Andrew :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following R code:

```
dataframe_name<-c("x1","x2","x3")
x1 <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2))
x2 <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2))
x3 <- data.frame(a=rep(1, 34))
dataframe_list<-list()

for(i in seq_along(dataframe_name)){ #note the different syntax for for loops in R
  if(nrow(get(dataframe_name[i]))==34){
    dataframe_list[[dataframe_name[i]]] <- get(dataframe_name[i]) #new element of the list by the original name of the dataframe
  }
}
```

Comment: Or `Filter(function(x) nrow(x) == 34, mget(dataframe_name))`